# How to define an Angular internal service and make it not injectable outside of its module?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, lazy-loading, angular-services, angular-module

Is there anyways to prevent a service from being injected outside of its original module?

Say that we're loading the `projects.module.ts` lazily and `ProjectsModule` is importing the `ProjectsStoreModule`. I have a service defined in `ProjectsStoreModule` that I don't want to be injected in the `ProjectsModule`, but it's ok to be injected anywhere inside the `ProjectsStoreModule`. I was wondering if there's a way to achieve this?

**Note:** `ProjectsStoreModule` does not have any Components so I can't provide the service to a component. The service that I want to be isolated is going to be injected in an Ngrx Effect which is a service.

**What I did:**

I registered the `ProjectsService`:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: ProjectsStoreModule
})
export class ProjectsService {
    ...
}
```

ProjectsModule:

```
@NgModule({
    ...
})
export class ProjectsModule {
    ...
    imports: [ProjectsStoreModule] 
}
```

This approach obviously caused so many `Circular dependency` warnings.

Then I tried to register the `ProjectsService` in the `@NgModule` decorator:

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [ProjectsService]
})
export class ProjectsStoreModule {
    ...
}
```

Now the problem is that, by importing the `ProjectsStoreModule` into the `ProjectsModule`, the service that I wanted to be an internal service will be available in the `ProjectsModule`.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Don't provide it use the provider array of the module. Inject the service on the root component of the module, if the module has one. Or just provide it at any component declaration that inject the service. This will make the service only accessible for the component and its child component.

````
@Component({
    selector: "component",
    templateUrl: "./component.component.html",
    providers: [
       InternalServiceClass
    ]
})```
````

Comment: Well technically, it will still be accessible, just not usable as you will get runtime errors for not providing it.

Comment: This won't work since the `ProjectsStoreModule` doesn't have any Components. The internal service is gonna be injected into the ngrx effect.

Comment: You’ll probably have to wire it up manually then. Nothing requires you to use a module-level injector.

Comment: And for that matter, nothing requires you to use DI. You could easily declare a singleton or static class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a way to prevent service from being injected outside its original module.

First you'll have to create a module for your service i.e `ProjectServiceModule`

Later , register your service with the newly created `ProjectServiceModule` like below:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: ProjectsServiceModule
})
export class ProjectsService {
    ...
}
```

Now include the `ProjectServiceModule` in your NgModule :

```
@NgModule({
 imports :[ProjectServiceModule]
})
export class ProjectsStoreModule {
    ...
}
```

This solution will remove your circular dependency errors while building the application and also solve your problem as this module is imported only in the `ProjectsStoreModule`

[Refer this link for more info](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-angular-6-dependency-injection-providedin-vs-providers-85b7a347b59f)

Comment: by importing the `ProjectsServiceModule` into the `ProjectsStoreModule`, the service will be available to any modules that imports the `ProjectsStoreModule`.

Comment: @HamidBehnam you are using the ``ProjectsStoreModule`` and injecting it into a lazily loaded module . If you are importing ``ProjectsStoreModule`` into every other module other than ``ProjectStoreModule`` then creating a feature module for a  store would be pointless and yes the service will be available everywhere the module is imported .

Comment: CruelEngine the reason that I created the `ProjectsStoreModule` was because it's supposed to be imported in some other modules based on their needs. For instance we might need to show the projects data in `.../projects` page or `.../dashboard` page, but not all the pages. The reason that I want the `ProjectsService` to be isolated is because I don't want the users of the module be able to bypass the redux structure by injecting the `ProjectsService` and sending the request directly to the server.